# Manipulate index of for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

Is it possible to manipulate the index pointer in a Python for loop?

For example in PHP the following example will print `1 3`:

```
$test = array(1,2,3,4);
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++){
    print $test[$i].' ';
    $i++;
}
```

However in Python there is no effect when I try to increment the index. For example the following will print all the numbers:

```
test = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for i in xrange(len(test)):
  print test[i]
  i=i+1
```

Is there a way to manipulate the for loop pointer inside the loop so I can implement some complex logic (e.g. go back 2 steps and then forward 3)? I know there may be alternative ways to implement my algorithm (and that's what I do at the moment) but I'd like to know if Python offers this ability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. The python loop is meant to iterate over a predefined iterator and thus does not directly allow modifying its progress. But you can of course do the same as in php:

```
test = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
i = 0
while i < len(test):
    print test[i]
    # Do anything with i here, e.g.
    i = i - 2
    # This is part of the loop
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 9):

When you try to manipulate the index `i` you are doing it, but when the `for` loop goes to the next iteration, it assigns to `i` the next value of `xrange(len(test))` so it won't be affected by the manipulation you did.

You may want to try a `while` instead:

```
test = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
i = 0
while i < 4:
    print test[i]
    i += 2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I accepted the oldest one because your solutions were similar.

Comment: Yes I was writing the textual part of the answer when he posted it.

Answer (score 1):

For complex loop logic, you can set the step size to iterate over the array you create or use a lambda function.

```
#create an array
a = [3, 14, 8, 2, 7, 5]

#access every other element

for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
    print a[i]

#access every other element backwards

for i in range(len(a) - 1, 0, -2):
    print a[i]

#access every odd numbered index

g = lambda x: 2*x + 1
for i in range(len(a)):
if g(i) > len(a):
        break
else:
        print a[g(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The semantic of **for** is

> iterate over the elements of a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object

You could read more about **for** [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

So if you want to implement some logics when visiting a container, you should use **while** or other methods rather than **for**.