# Is there a way to manipulate the counter in a "for" loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

By "counter" I mean the "i" in the code I attached. I just picked up Python for University, and I was wondering if i could maniuplate the counter just like you can in C++

```
n=5
for i in range(n):
    print("Test")
    i=i-1
```

The result of this code is

**Test
Test
Test
Test
Test**

but i was wondering if you could manipulate the "i" so it is an infinite loop

Feel free to ask questions about what I mean if it is not clear enough

Comment: What do you really want to happen? Surely you don't want to have an infinite loop, right? You are not really using `i`. A better example could help understanding your question.

Comment: If you want an infinite loop, you may consider using something like `while True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *problem* is that python uses iterators, which aren't meant to be manipulated while getting iterated. A good rule is, if you need to manipulate a for loop, you shouldn't use a for loop. The better way would be, using a while loop. An example:

```
n = 10
while n > 5:
    print("Test " + n)
    n -= 2
    if n == 6:
        n += 1
```

Or the infinite loop:

```
while True:
    print("Test")
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794909/manipulate-index-of-for-loop-in-python) for more information.